# Land reform in Guatemala

Tags: economy, guatemala

Recently, after attending to a conference with some Guatemalan politicians, I began to take interest in this country's socio-economical issues, in particular with regard to land.

I that in the 1950s [they did a massive land reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decree_900), but it was canceled shortly afterwards by a USA-backed coup d'etat. It started a 40 years civil war which ended in 1996. After that, several government officials were put to trial for war crimes. The last thing I found in Wikipedia about the [history of Guatemala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Guatemala#President_Otto_P%C3%A9rez_Molina_government_and_%22La_L%C3%ADnea%22_case) is the recent scandal related to bribery in the government; it is not connected to land reform.

So, my questions are:

1. Has land-reform been attempted after the end of the civil war in 1996?
2. Is land-reform a major issue in current Guatemala politics?
3. What Guatemalan parties support/oppose land reform today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In short, no. Many people have argued for it but there have been no major attempts that made any headway.
2. It isn't a major issue in the terms that it isn't a topic that is debated actively in congress and no parties hold it as a major part of their policy ideals. This is important because the president holds a lot of power in Guatemala through executive branches so if they don't want it, it probably won't happen. Most people are more focused on the crime and corruption aspects in their country with land reform being an issue that is always around but almost never in the forefront. It mostly is used as a reasoning for the problems, both ways, and not as a solution.

This has been the status quo mainly because of US intervention and local policy that has geared their economy towards a modern-form of banana republic where only 2,5% of the farms own 2/3 of the land.
If you would like other examples of countries where land reform has and currently is taking front stage, since I see in your Bio you are interested in fair division of land as a subject, then I would suggest you look towards South Africa. They have in the last few years made that a center-point of two of the biggest parties policy lines and have actually amended the constitution to make it possible.